# is there a way to find ratio for size and width of div

Tags: css, sass, viewport-units

I have two sass variables for width and height of a certain div:

```
$width: 277.98px;
$height: 156.36px;
```

I want to convert this into some kind of ratio so that when adjusting the size of the screen, height and width are always proportionate to each other. The issue I was having was when trying to adjust width/height using viewport height or width (vh/vw) I kept getting errors like:

```
SassError: 27798px*vh isn't a valid CSS value.
```

Another issue is that I don't really understand how adjusting these dimensions by vh/vw even really works. What I'm looking for is the best way to go about adjusting the width and height of my div, so that they get bigger and smaller when changing screen size, but that they also stay proportionate to their original values (ratio-wise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aspect-ratio` is built into css.

In this example, `.box` has a height of `112.484px` because it is constrained by its parent `div`'s width of `200px`.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
}

.box {
  aspect-ratio: 277.98 / 156.36;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this worked for what i was asking. Just wondering if there's a way to do this with font sizes. Like if i always wanted a description to be 12px font compared to the div.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container